# openjdk: jdk8u build error in Solaris 11 X86

Tags: java-8, solaris, solaris-studio

When i try to build openjdk 8u 64-bit from https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/ in Solaris 11 X86:
Error:

```
configure: Resolving CC (as /opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/cc) failed, using /opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/cc directly.
checking resolved symbolic links for CC... /opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/cc
checking if CC is disguised ccache... no, keeping CC
configure: The C compiler (located as /opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/cc) does not seem to be the required Sun Studio compiler.
configure: The result from running with -V was: "cc: Studio 12.6 Sun C 5.15 SunOS_i386 2017/05/30" and with --version: "cc: Warning: Option --version passed to ld, if ld is invoked, ignored otherwise"
configure: error: Sun Studio compiler is required. Try setting --with-tools-dir.
configure exiting with result code 1
```

1. I've successfully built jdk8u 64-bit in Solaris 10 x86.
2. What compiler version does jdk8u support for building 64-bit in Solaris 11? Will that same compiler supported by Solaris 11. I see Solaris 11 supports developer studio from 12.4.

I would like to know whether we can build openjdk-jdk8u 64-bit version in Solaris 11.

Comment: Are you trying to build a 32-bit JVM on Solaris 11?  That's not supported.

Comment: Question edited:Build Openjdk- jdk8u 64-bit in Solaris 11.4 x86.